# Who is going to the Moon in 2022? How many planned missions to land something there?

Tags: launch, the-moon

How many planned missions are there that plan to land something on the Moon in 2022?

Secured access to launch necessary to count, no washing-machine with bottle-rocket missions.

Please include a link for each for verification.

Comment: I'd like too! But I don't qualify.  :-(  Beside, there's bound to be some form of Covid-19 restrictions & quarantine etc., blah, blah, blah, blah ... By that time we will have probably gone past the omega strain & on to the [Andromeda Strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andromeda_Strain_(film))